# CDC not enabled when using login account with sysadmin roles

Tags: sql, security, system-administration, cdc

I get an error when trying to enable CDC on one of our SQL2012 instances, when using a login account that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

`Procedure sp_cdc_enable_db_internal`,

> Could not update the metadata that indicates database 
>   is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when
>   executing the command 'SetCDCTracked(Value = 1)' Could not obtain
>   information about WindowsNT group/user"

The login account in question created the database initially so is mentioned in the "Login name:" under the dbo user for this particular database.

When I ran sp_changedbowner 'sa' on the database and then ran the command again to enable CDC it worked. Why is that?

I thought that to enable CDC you either had to be a member of the 'db_owner' role in the actual database OR a member of the sysadmin role.

Can some one help explain to me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ramoji/could-not-update-the-metadata-that-indicates-database-is-enabled-for-change-data-capture-the-failure-occurred-when-executing-the-command-setcdctrackedvalue-1
2. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/913423/you-cannot-run-a-statement-or-a-module-that-includes-the-execute-as-cl

> This problem occurs because SQL Server 2005 cannot obtain the information about the context when you try to impersonate a database user to run a statement or a module.